# Weka in Java cannot load in model after changing the source code

Tags: java, serialization, weka, random-forest

Recently, I was working on some `Random Forest` model of `Java`. My professor asked me to load in a `Random Forest` model she gave me and print out the rules of it.

Since I need to print the detailed rules (which, I believe, is a not offered function for `Random Forest`), I have to change some codes. However, after I changed the codes, Java serialization does not allow me load in the model perfectly, there are always some `Null Pointer Exception`.

I think, according to `Java` doc, if I only changes some minor parts of the source code, I should be allowed to load in the model and in order to minimize the changes, I only change some `private` or `protected` to `public`. So that I can access the detail to the class, but even this kind of changing is not satisfying.

I hope someone can give me some clue about these:

1. It is possible to do de-serialization if I only change some `protected` to `public`, right?
   Also, I guess there could be some problems if I still have some `protected` unchanged, but this will definitely raise an compile error, right? Do I need to search through the codes for some potential unchanged `protected`?
2. Is there any better way to print the `Random Forest` rules?

I have been working on this problem for two weeks and I really hope someone can help me about that.

The source code with exception is:

```
 int maxIndex = Utils.maxIndex(m_Distribution[0]);
```

It is at the Line 656 of these code
https://github.com/HaohanWang/WekaRandomForest/blob/master/src/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomTree.java

I did not make any changes more than change `protected` to `public`, but I add another class in a new package to print the rules by these following codes:

```
if (m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers == null) {
        System.out.println("Bagging: No model built yet.");
    } 
else {
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
        text.append("All the base classifiers: \n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers.length; i++)
            if (m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers[i] == null) {
                System.out.println("Oh, aaaaa");
            } else {
                text.append(m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers[i]
                        .toString() + "\n\n");
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(text.toString());
    }
```

Comment: include the code that raises the exception. And add detail to explain what you've tried.

Comment: By changing methods from protected to public are you trying to access the individual RandomTrees?  That seems to be the logical thing to do to begin printing rules.  If so, could you write your own method to get the "m_classifiers", and add it to the RandomForest class of Weka?

Comment: @Renaissance Thanks, I have pasted the code with exception and my codes here.

Comment: @Walter Thanks, yes I try to reach each individual tree. I just put my codes up there, please have a look